# How to increment a variable every time i send a mail through smtp

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, increment

I have a mailer and here is the code:

```
 private static int i=0; 
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {    
     ++i; //i want to increment this variable

            {
                SendHTMLMail();
            }


            void SendHTMLMail()
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/one.html"));
                string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
                string myString = "";
                myString = readFile;



                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

                Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text);

                Msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
                Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
                Msg.Body = myString.ToString();
                Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                if (fuAttachment.HasFile)
                {
                    string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);

                    Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));
                }

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtpwd.Text);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Msg);
                Msg = null;
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);

                // Request both failure and success report
                Msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure | DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;

                int emailsSent = 0;

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("start to send email ...");
                    smtp.Send(Msg);
                    emailsSent++;
                    Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

in the above code, i have a variable 'i' and i want to increment it every time i send the mail. Now the problem i am facing is that 'i' is getting incremented only when i am sending mail again and again when my aspx page in localhost is opened. As soon as i close my aspx page, re-opens it and send the mail again, then the variable 'i' is again getting incremented to one and not to say 4 or 5.

Comment: This is expected behavior, since this is a web application. It's being recycled by web server due to inactivity. Next time you're requesting page, you're geting *new* application instance - this is new app domain, and all static data has its defaults. You need some persistent storage: database, file, browser cache, etc.

Comment: You will need to persist that number in your backend. Keeping it as static field of that class is not enough. A restart will reset it. (+ What Dennis says ...)

Comment: how to do that ? @Dennis

Comment: @manusharma: How to do *what*? You should be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Behavior changes where you put this code. If it's in ASPX pages, you'll loose static data whenever runtime recompile that page. If it's in DLL files, you'll loose values whenever application/IIS Pool recycles. You need to save final values into a persistent store (ie Database). Next time you need them, you must retrieve from DB, increment it then save again. 
Be careful, web applications are multi-thread and static variables are not thread safe. If two threads modify same variable at the same time you'll run into chaos. Use locking mechanism to access static variables in multi-threaded applications.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: First create another static object (`code`static readony object myLockObject = new object();)  Then use it to serialize access your variable (`code`lock(myLockObject){ myStaticVariable++; })

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a separate static class for it- (because if you hit refresh / reload page in asp.net life cycle the entire page gets reloaded along with the objects.)

Define a static class (or a non static class with its constructor called) with variable/property to be incremented every time you send mail.

```
public static class Mail
{
       private static int mailCount;

       public static void MailSent()
       {
          mailCount++;
       }

       public static int GetMailCount()
       {
          return mailCount;
       }
}
```

Now in your button click use the static methods to increment and retrieve of mailCount-

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Mail.MailSent(); // increments every time you send mail
     // to check how many mails sent in debug console
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Mail.GetMailCount()); 
     //... YOU MAILING CODE
}
```

[image]

Comment: i have create a class as you said and calling the GetMailCount() function in the aspx page but it always show one

Comment: but it is not working. every time it is getting incremented again from 0 to 1

Comment: @manusharma you are just obscure.. tell me about how you implemented this class, unless i dont know how you did it i cant troubleshoot it

Comment: What have you written in your aspx page?

Comment: @manusharma just a button click event thats it.. and a seperate class file Mail.cs

Comment: i am doing this in my button click                                                                                       Addin.MailSent();
   i = Addin.GetMailCount();  //assigning it to a variable as i want to send the incremented value to database

Comment: and here is the class i have added  -                                                               public class Addin
    {
        private static int mailCount;

        public static void MailSent()
        {
            mailCount++;
        }

        public static int GetMailCount()
        {
            return mailCount;
        }
    }

Comment: @manusharma the code you posted in comment should work and i will get the new incremented value, also can you format your code in the question properly, i see that you have defined a method within a method scope which is illegal. This is the best solution solution i can offer.

Comment: i just want to store the incremented value in a variable as i want to send it in a query string. There is no issue with mail.cs just tell me how to get the incremented value in the button click and assign it ti a variable say i.